# How to get MAAS server URL from command line?

Tags: server, vmware, maas

I just wanted to try out MAAS dashboard so, i have created a MAAS server on ubuntu server 14.04 in VMware. However, i did not get the prompt for setting server URL as http://10.x.x.x/MAAS as described [here](https://maas.ubuntu.com/docs1.5/install.html#disc-install).

I tried reinstalling it several times, but never made out till that prompt. The setup then continues as normal till end.

So, is there any way to get server URL from command line ?

Comment: Are you setting up a region controller on the VMWare server or a cluster controller? This information may help based on a quick scan of the documentation you refer to.

Comment: I wasn't trying to setup any region or cluster controller(and i don't know what this both terms mean). Actually i don't know. I just wanted to try out MAAS dashboard, so i was trying to install it on VMware.

Answer (score 0):

You can learn more about MAAS [here](https://maas.ubuntu.com/) and also [here.](http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/tools/maas)

Installation instructions are available to [read here](http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/install.html)

There is further documentation on this [page.](http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs)

You can get the local ip address of any ubuntu machine by opening a terminal and issuing the command:

`ifconfig` which will produce results including a line similar to this:

`inet addr:192.168.15.131` in which case the local ipv4 address is 192.168.15.131

You can obtain your outside ip address on [this](http://www.whatsmyip.org/) page